# How to alter the default user permisions based on a returned value after login?

Tags: users, 6

I am having some users who have access to a limited modules. Now after a user logs in, i want to alter the permissions of that user based on the uid. I mean i should be able to add or delete some permissions of that user immediately after a user logs in. Immediately after login i wrote a custom code which executes and returns a value whether the user is active or inactive. Then based on the result i should be able to delete some permissions to access some modules of my site if inactive or add if he is active.

Comment: Are they fine grained per-user?  Seems like more of a job for user roles to be honest.

Comment: Yes, they are. Working on it but not able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

[user_role_grant_permissions](http://api.drupal.or/user_role_grant_permissions) can help you. Or you are using modules which grant permissions based on users not on roles? If yes, look into code of module which control permissions per user to find proper function

Comment: I am using drupal 6 and the function you suggested is for drupal 7 and more. By the way I'm not using any modules which grant permissions based on users.

Comment: Are you using user roles, if so you can achieve this by changing roles of user dynamically based on your conditions.